# Using "select * from" to select and identify clashing reservations in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

So I tried making a reservation system for a games library.

```
$timestamp = (strtotime($StartDate));
$EndDate = strtotime("+$Duration days",$timestamp);
```

This part of the code converts the date entered into a form into a timestamp
The second line of the code calculates the end date timestamp for reserving the game for a certain number of days.

In my mind, how I would do it is by creating a variable and selecting certain values from the database. However, I am not that good at php, so I am not a 100% sure if I am right:

```
$reserved = mysql_query ("SELECT count(*) FROM reservations WHERE EndDate <= $EndDate AND StartDate >= $timestamp");
if (!$reserved) { /*do nothing*/ } ELSE { echo "That date has already been reserved"; }
```

What this should do is select the timestamps from the database which clash, and then I can display an error message if the variable $reserved is not empty. However, I can't get it to work. How do I display the error message properly?

Comment: do a count(*) in your select or num_rows, then `if > 0` or `==1` display message, else, display something else. Google "if row exists mysql php". best I can offer without knowing which API you're using to connect with.

Comment: @Fred -ii-
I am using mysql to connect

    mysql_connect("servername","username","password") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @M Bloxman : Have you used `mysql_query()` function to execute the query?

Comment: Your “example code” suggests that you don’t know the very basics of working with MySQL in PHP – so please go read some beginner’s tutorials on that. SO is not the place to teach you the basics.

Comment: Also note that all `mysql_` functions are deprecated in PHP 5 and will be removed in PHP 7 (to be released later this year). Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @CBroe I know the basics, but I am only a beginner, so I may have missed a few things. What I mean is that I may not be able to write code properly, but I can understand php coding easily, and can identify what I have done wrong by looking at answers that people have given me. And so can other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use as below :

```
    $result = mysql_query("Select * from reservations where StartDate >= '".$timestamp."' AND  EndDate <= '".$EndDate."'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows==0)
    { 
       //Your Process 
    } 
    else 
    { echo "That date has already been reserved"; }
```

Comment: You could re-phase the if statement, so you don't have a "do nothing" clause (and also you accidentally commented out a `}`) -> `if($num_rows!==0) { echo "That date has already been reserved"; }`

Comment: If you're only interested in the number of rows a query returns, you should not return all rows but instead let MySQL do the counting for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realised I had made a few silly mistakes in my code. For example I had forgotten the 'mysql_query' part. The '$num_rows' function had completely slipped my mind, so thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: @M Bloxman : That's great, it helped you..